# Google Chrome 64bit window drags on resize

Tags: google-chrome

It's easy to tell what the problem is in the picture, but in Chrome when I re-size the window everything kind of .... drags. Only Chrome does this.

I've tried the 64 bit version of Chrome, the 32 bit version, and now Chromium. I got Chromium from the software center.

Also, I'm really new to Linux.

[image]

Update:

**SYSTEM SPECS**

- Lenovo Y400
- Intel Core i7
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 750M

I just tried installing an Nvidia driver from [here](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/61453) and I got an error saying Xorg drivers were already installed.

Comment: Please post your system specs, including videocard/integrated graphics.

Comment: Just posted my system specs.

Comment: This needs some community wiki, as this isn't very localized, and someone else can and will have the same problem.

Comment: How do I community wiki

Comment: When you're *answering* a question and you have enough reputation, you can check a box on the bottom right of the markdown entry box, to make it a community wiki. This doesn't apply to questions.

Answer (score 2):

Looks to me like a problem with your video drivers. You could try installing proprietary  drivers (from Nvidia or ATI) using the Additional Drivers tool, to see if that clears up the issue.

You mentioned that you tried the 64 bit, 32 bit and Chromium, I assume they all do this but never Firefox. This would imply that it's something (a library, perhaps) that Chrome uses, but Firefox doesn't. You could also check to make sure that you've got everything up to date (Use the Update Manager or `sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get upgrade` in terminal.)

Comment: I think I'll try installing a proprietary driver. Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'd upvote you but that requires 15 reputation.